# Command line arguments with forward slash not working correctly

Tags: c#

I am trying to run an application that accepts command line arguments from within a C# application, when I launch the application without arguments, it works fine, but if I put in the arguments, I see a window flash on the screen for only a second. The arguments contain forward slashes.
Here is the code:

```
private void BtnStartStress_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Process GpuTest = new Process();            
        GpuTest.StartInfo.FileName = @"C:\Users\Computer_User\source\repos\StressTool\GpuTest\GpuTest.exe";
        GpuTest.StartInfo.Arguments = "/test=fur";
        GpuTest.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
        GpuTest.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = false;
        GpuTest.Start();
    }
```

I can't figure out why it won't work with the arguments.

Edit: I found it works if I put the executable (and related DLLs) in the bin folder with the executable for my application. The issue appears to be with the GpuTest executable being in a different folder than my application's executable.

FYI, the software I am using is the GPU Test from Geeks3D https://www.geeks3d.com/gputest/

Comment: Does it work when you run the same from the command prompt? And what exactly are you expecting to happen? Based on what's written in the description of the tool, if you run it with an argument, it will show nothing and just output the results into a text file. Is there some problem with the output? Keep in mind that the output would usually be in the working directory, which you don't set explicitly.

Comment: Just add `Console.ReadLine()` so that  the launched window won't be automatically closed when the program closes. Then you will be able to see any message displayed by the program if any.

Comment: Adding the Console.ReadLine(); does not stop the window from closing. It will only stop my application from closing, which it isn't doing anyway as it is a GUI application.